# Phonegap Facebook Plugin fail when post to wall on Android

Tags: android, facebook, cordova

i have an issue with Phonegap Facebook Plugin. I follow link https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin to setup a phonegap app using facebook. But app crash when i using post api, i can use login api. This is error message :

> 10-06 01:23:04.600: E/AndroidRuntime(889): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   10-06 01:23:04.600: E/AndroidRuntime(889): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
>   10-06 01:23:04.600: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1118)
>   10-06 01:23:04.600: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:693)
>   10-06 01:23:04.600: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at com.facebook.android.FbDialog.createCrossImage(FbDialog.java:107)
>   10-06 01:23:04.600: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at com.facebook.android.FbDialog.onCreate(FbDialog.java:81)
>   10-06 01:23:04.600: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:355)
>   10-06 01:23:04.600: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:260)
>   10-06 01:23:04.600: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at com.facebook.android.Facebook.dialog(Facebook.java:839)
>   10-06 01:23:04.600: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at org.apache.cordova.facebook.ConnectPlugin$2.run(ConnectPlugin.java:178)
>   10-06 01:23:04.600: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
>   10-06 01:23:04.600: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>   10-06 01:23:04.600: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   10-06 01:23:04.600: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
>   10-06 01:23:04.600: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   10-06 01:23:04.600: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
>   10-06 01:23:04.600: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
>   10-06 01:23:04.600: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
>   10-06 01:23:04.600: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

What should i do?

Thanks